# Deducing class template arguments with a constructor that uses a member type alias

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

So apparently this is supposed to work:

```
template<class T>
struct C {
   using value_type = T;
   C(value_type);
};

C c(1); // C<int>
```

As is this (see the `B` example in [[over.match.class.deduct]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.match.class.deduct#3)):

```
template<class T>
struct D {
   template<class> using meow_t = T;

   template<class U>
   D(U, meow_t<U>);
};

D d(1, 'c'); // D<char>
```

Note that a seemingly-equivalent explicit guide won't work since the parameter is a non-deduced context:

```
template<class T>
C(typename C<T>::value_type) -> C<T>;
```

While it's certainly *desirable* that at least the first snippet works, I haven't yet been able to find the wording that actually *makes* it work in the current working draft. Does anyone know where it is?

Comment: Unrelated: shouldn't `d(1, 'c')` spit out an error similar to `deduced conflicting types for parameter 'T' ('int' and 'char')`? Or here `meow_t<U>` is in a non-deduced context? But if yes then the comment in the code is wrong, `// D<char>` should be `// D<int>`.

Comment: No. `meow_t<U>` is `T`.

Comment: Right, that's what I thought. But then in `d(1, 'c')` you have an `int` and a `char`. Why would type deduction work here as (afaik) there are no conversions performed? For example, this pre-C++1z example doesn't compile: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f57c46020edd62fd

Comment: Look at it again, it's `T`, not `U`.

Comment: Ohh yes, thanks, my bad!

Comment: The example at the end [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0620r0.html) suggests that the first snippet doesn't actually work and you need an explicit deduction guide?

Comment: @Barry The `A` one from 13.3.3? It doesn't actually say that it won't work without #6; the purpose of that example is to illustrate the guide/nonguide tiebreaker (i.e., #6 doesn't cause an ambiguity with #1), as far as I can tell.

Comment: Can't tell. Strikes me as a pretty bad example.

Comment: @Barry Also probably to illustrate that the guide doesn't win over the copy deduction candidate, i.e., copy is preferred over wrapping. Since the second snippet is definitely supposed to work, and large swaths of class template argument deduction in the library depends on the first snippet working, I think it's a safe assumption.

Comment: @T.C. What depends on the first snippet working? I was even sitting in Core in Oulu when we discussed this exact problem but I can't remember what the resolution was outside of like "this should work."

Comment: @Barry E.g. `std::mutex m; std::lock_guard l(m);`

Comment: @T.C. But it's specified as `lock_guard(MutexTypes&...)`, not as an alias.

Comment: @Barry Nope, it's `lock_guard(mutex_type&)`. You are thinking about the thing now called `scoped_lock`.

Comment: [CWG issue 2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2)

Comment: @T.C. ok that changed since N4618, this stuff changes quickly. You're right.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't strictly an answer, as I don't think such wording actually exists. This is more of a cobbling together of information related to the question.

---

This is [Core Issue 2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2). The discussion in Oulu and Issaquah about this feature made it clear that the *intent* is that looking through the typedefs is valid, but no wording as added to indicate as to how this is supposed to work - it just... is. The wording as-is suggests that the deduction guide for:

```
template<class T>
struct C {
   using value_type = T;
   C(value_type);
};
```

would be:

```
template <class T> C<T> foo(typename C<T>::value_type );
```

which would be a non-deduced context and fail, yet [[thread.lock.guard]](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.lock.guard) does not have an explicit deduction guide for this case.

The example in [[over.match.best]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over#match.best-1.10) is apparently intended to indicate that typedefs are supposed to work, although none of the examples in that example actually use #1 as the deduction guide:

> ```
> template <class T> struct A {
>   using value_type = T;
>   A(value_type);    // #1
>   A(const A&);      // #2
>   A(T, T, int);     // #3
>   template<class U>
>     A(int, T, U);   // #4
>   // #5 is the copy deduction candidate, A(A)
> };
>
> A x(1, 2, 3);       // uses #3, generated from a non-template constructor
>
> template <class T>
> A(T) -> A<T>;       // #6, less specialized than #5
>
> A a(42);            // uses #6 to deduce A<int> and #1 to initialize
> A b = a;            // uses #5 to deduce A<int> and #2 to initialize
>
> template <class T>
> A(A<T>) -> A<A<T>>; // #7, as specialized as #5
>
> A b2 = a;           // uses #7 to deduce A<A<int>> and #1 to initialize
> ```

Comment: It isn't quite CWG2, though. Deduction guides aren't members, and the functions/function templates synthesized from them aren't members of the original class template.

Comment: @T.C. Yeah, not exactly, but it's in the same orbit. I suspect this'll just add on to the heap of template-related issues that are underpsecified in the standard.

Comment: @T.C. Want to throw something into std-discussion?

Comment: I believe the way we described this in discussion at Issaquah was "vigorous handwaving occurs here". The intended rule is that of CWG 2: if you can figure out what the type is by using only information from the template, then you can against that type. (Put another way, if it would be valid to redeclare the constructor using a deducible type, you get to deduce against that type. But that takes you back to CWG 2 to determine when the redeclaration is valid.)

Answer (score 0):

I think a careful reading makes this clear:

> The types of the function parameters are those of the constructor.

Note that `C<T>::value_type` is not a type, it is a typedef-name.  Due to substitution, the type of the constructor parameter is `T`, and the equivalent deduction guide is actually

```
template <class T> C(T) -> C<T>;
```

In your example, using `C<T>::value_type` made it seem liked there was an issue with a non-deduced context, but that issue doesn't actually exist because there is no lookup involved for the deduction function parameters.

Comment: The same argument applies to `T`: "it is a *typedef-name*" (see [temp.param]/3); it "is not a type". I don't see how you can draw a principled distinction here based on that argument.

Comment: I see your point, but it is the closest I can get with code. Using `value_type` is not as close, and it leads to the issue with it seeming like a non-deduced context, which isn't actually relevant, since there is no lookup involved.

Comment: The constructor in question is, unlike in every other situation, a member of a class _template_, not a class (_e.g.,_ a class template specialization).  Its parameter type _is_ `T` because no value for `T` has yet been provided.  Yes, this is an ugly language hack.